# SQL Server + Reporting Services + SSIS + SSAS Licensing and Infrastructure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssrs, license, ssis

Actually I am running 3 environments (Dev / UAT / PROD ) with SQL Server installations on them.

Development server has also Integration Services Service running on it an we are starting to actively using it.

We are thinking also on installing Reporting Service to start using the whole suite provided by Microsoft. And here comes my question.

I'm not really sure if having everything on same server with huge workloads and usage is a good idea and maybe isolating each component on its own server would be the best option. However, how is licensing applied in this case?

Is it possible to have:

- 1 MSSQL Server with Data Engine and Databases on it.
- 1 Server with Integration Services on it (Does it need Database or something?)
- 1 Server with Reporting Services on it (Does it need Database or something?)

You have to license all 3 servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Licensing Guide (PDF)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=230678).

Page 11 says:

> The software components of a single SQL Server 2014 license cannot be separated for use in more than one OSE. If these components are running on a server other than the main database server, then an additional license is required for each additional OSE in which they are installed. For example, if the SQL Server DB is deployed in one OSE and SQL Server RS is deployed in another, both OSEs must be fully licensed for SQL Server 2014 accordingly.

What that means is that if you run the database engine, SSIS, and SSRS on three separate servers, then you have to license all three.

Comment: I think you are refering to licensing a server and then virtualizing, that could be interesting but my servers are VMs already.
Thanks a lot for your time Brent, this document was really helpful.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention virtualization in the question. OK, great, glad I could help.